# Spring serve static resource with addResourceHandlers: doesn't load file from /home/username/ folder: Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm following  [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources) on serving static resources with Spring.

I have this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer  {
 

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/home/username/springfiles");
    }
}
```

the `/home/username/springfiles` contains:

```
test.txt
pic.jpg
```

I try to access each at

```
http://localhost:8082/files/test.txt
```

```
http://localhost:8082/files/pic.jpg
```

and

```
http://localhost:8082/test.txt
```

```
http://localhost:8082/pic.jpg
```

However I get

```
Whitelabel Error Page
```

error.

What am I doing wrong?

I need my application to be able to save files (images and audio) in `/home/username/springfiles` (as I've read it's better practice as opposed to saving in a database as blobs), and retrieve those files (but only to verified users).